# Ubuntu with ZFS not able to boot

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub, zfs

I have a server with 8 4TB HDDs, and I decided to try to manage it with ZFS on Ubuntu instead of with the RAID card built into the server. To do this I partitioned a disk in two, one for the installation and the other left unpartitioned for ZFS. Once the installation was finished I created a pool with the seven remaining disks and the unused partition on the "primary" disk.

Everything went smoothly but today when I opened up the console I couldn't do anything, and then I noticed an error message for dist-upgrade, which exited with error code 139 and resulted in a segmentation fault.

I had to reboot the server manually and when it came back up, I could no longer boot to Ubuntu. In fact in the GRUB shell I cannot even see the root partition anymore, it treats the "primary" disk as if it were entirely part of the ZFS pool. I can still mount it but it only shows the EFI partition, nothing else. When I try to boot a live CD, it again shows the disk having only one 4TB partition, but if I mount it it correctly shows the 500MB EFI partition.

At this point I am very confused, I would really like to having to wipe the system, since I believe my root partition is still there and it is somehow not being seen by the system, as if it were "blocked" by the ZFS partition.

Any help is very much appreciated!